# Add-Migration fails with Dependency injection in console core 2.0 app

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I try to use EF Core 2.0 in a console .net core 2.0 application. When i either use `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` or override `OnConfiguring` method of a `DbContext` derived class `CustomerDbContext`, then `Add-Migration` is successfull in package manager console. But if i try to use `AddDbContext` like in an asp.net core application, i receive the message:

`Unable to create an object of type 'CustomerDbContext'`

The code snippet for console .net core application is:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        IConfigurationRoot config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("config.json")     //needs Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json
            .Build();

        string conn = config.GetConnectionString("WarehouseConnection");
        services
            .AddDbContext<CustomerDbContext>(
            options => options.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("WarehouseConnection")));

        var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        using(var context = provider.GetService<CustomerDbContext>())
        {
             ...   
        }

    }

}
```

the `config.json` contains the connection string:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "WarehouseConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=WAREHOUSE;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
}
```

the `CustomerDbContext` class is:

```
class CustomerDbContext : DbContext   
{
    public CustomerDbContext(DbContextOptions<CustomerDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

Any ideas why this approach fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from 2.0, the EF tool checks for a `BuildWebHost()` method and uses it to access application services if it exsits. Since you don't need a `BuildWebHost()` using `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` is the right approach.

Check [the announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/258) and [this comment in the discussion](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9033#issuecomment-313148393) for more information.

Comment: or overriding the `OnConfiguring` method inside a derived class from `DbContext`

Comment: @maclaud if tightly coupling the DbContext with the `DbContextOptions` options is okay, then `OnConfiguring` is fine :)

Answer (score 1):

So you need to implement `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` interface. Add a class that implements this interface inside of your project.

```
public class DesignTimeDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<AppDbContext>
{
    public CustomerDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<CustomerDbContext>();
        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("WarehouseConnection");
        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

        return new CustomerDbContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

For more info read [Cannot make migration. ef core 2.0](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9415)

Comment: Yes i know that. But what i 'm asking is, why the above code snippet that resembles the asp.net core implementation, fails.